# Add and remove class depending on location in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add a class only when I'm at the root path.

**What I've want**

I want my header to have a class `fixed` when it's at the root path and be removed when it goes somewhere else.

**What I've done**

I have in my html:

```
<header ng-class="currentPath === '/' ? 'main-header fixed' : 'main-header' ">
```

and on my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('hipodromoApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    $scope.currentPath = $location.path();


  });
```

My html always returns the false one `main-header` without the `fixed` class.

**question**

How do I add a class called `fixed` to my html only when I'm at the root path `/` and remove it when I go somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around a solution for this.

I created an `index_controller` with the following:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name hipodromoApp.controller:IndexControllerCtrl
 * @description
 * # IndexControllerCtrl
 * Controller of the hipodromoApp
 */
angular.module('hipodromoApp')
  .controller('IndexControllerCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    // console.log($location.path());


  });

// this will run every time the route changes
angular.module('hipodromoApp')
    .run(['$rootScope','$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        var location = $location.path();

        if (location == '/') {
                $rootScope.bodyClass = 'fixed';
        }else{
            $rootScope.bodyClass = '';
        }
    });
  }]);
```

and added the controller in the index.html

```
<div class="" ng-view=""  ng-controller="IndexControllerCtrl"></div>
```

and just added this

```
<header class="main-header {{bodyClass}}">
```

the `{{bodyClass}}` will change to `fixed` when it goes to the root path and then to an empty string when it's in a different route.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve this but did what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you do works for me. It would make sense for me to remove the main-header from ng-class and just put it in a regular class, but that might be a personal favor.

Did you console.log your $scope.currentPath? I think it might not be /.
And are you sure that you're looking in the right scope? No ng-repeat child scope or something along those lines.